# mysqlでレコードがない場合のみ挿入したい

Tags: mysql, mariadb

mysqlでレコードを挿入する際に、挿入したいデータが既にレコードがある場合は挿入せず、ない場合にのみ挿入したいです。
下記のsqlをコマンドラインから実行しました。

```
insert into fileinfo (filename, url) values ("a", "aa") where not exists (select * from fileinfo where filename = "a");
```

下記のエラーがでました。

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where not exists (select * from fileinfo where filename = "a")' at line 1
```

どこが間違っているのかわかりません

CentOS7
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.34-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
です。

DB構造は下記の通りです。

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| filename | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| url      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 確認ですが、`fileinfo` テーブルの `filename` カラムは primary key でしょうか？

Comment: 申し訳ありません。DB構造の情報が不足していましたので、質問を編集しました。

Comment: [この回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3164741)が参考になるかと思います。この場合は、`insert into fileinfo (filename, url) select 'a', 'aa' from dual where not exists (select * from fileinfo where filename = 'a');` などとすると良いかと。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下のリファレンスよりmariadbでは`insert into values`に直接`where`句は記述できません。
[INSERT - MariaDB Knowledge Base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert/)

次の参考URLより
[mysqlでデータが存在するときinsertしないDML - まがりの日記](http://oomatomo.hatenablog.com/entry/33737434)

```
insert into fileinfo (filename, url) 
select * from (select'a', 'aa') as tmp
where not exists  (select * from fileinfo where filename = 'a') limit 1
```

とすれば目的の通り、動作するようです。

`ignore`を使った方法も参考URLに記述されていますが、こちらはDBが出力する重複エラーを無視するという方法なので、あまりいい方法ではありません。

書いているうちにコメントで回答がありますね。
せっかく書いたので投稿しておきます。

Answer (score 1):

> mysqlでレコードを挿入する際に、挿入したいデータが既にレコードがある場合は挿入せず、ない場合にのみ挿入したいです。

もし、filenameを NOT NULLにできる場合、UNIQUE制約を検討したほうが良いと思います。

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE fileinfo (
    ->   id int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   filename varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   url varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (id),
    ->   UNIQUE (filename)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into fileinfo (filename, url) values ("a", "aa");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into fileinfo (filename, url) values ("a", "aa");
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'a' for key 'filename'
```

他の解答でもあるように、IGNOREもできますし、ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATEというオプションも使えるようになります。

```
mysql> select * from fileinfo;
+----+----------+------+
| id | filename | url  |
+----+----------+------+
|  1 | a        | a    |
+----+----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into fileinfo (filename, url) values ("a", "url") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url = "new url";
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from fileinfo;
+----+----------+---------+
| id | filename | url     |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 | a        | new url |
+----+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

INDEXもつくため、索引のスピードも早くなります。

[この解答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3164595/8299670)を参考にしました。
MySQLの[insert-on-duplicateのドキュメント](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)